# I would like to create a user/password to login to vagrant vm via VirtualBox GUI

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile, coreos

I would like to use a username/password to log into a vagrant virtual machine via Virtualbox's GUI

I'm new to Vagrant and I thought that I could login, through the virtualbox gui, using the following:

```
username: vagrant
password: vagrant
```

However, it is not working with my setup.

I've attached links to the following for your consideration:

[My Vagrantfile](http://textuploader.com/5yy28)  (file)

[vagrant up (output)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2yNL.jpg) (image)

[virtualbox gui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYxTM.jpg) (image)

My Vagrantfile is based off [coreos-vagrant's](https://github.com/coreos/coreos-vagrant) github.

I can `vagrant ssh` into the box, but I would like to be able to login via the VirtualBox. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance and any other suggestions on what I'm doing wrong are also welcomed!